Movie where young boy looks for his father after surviving a plane crash
Saw a movie as a child about the trials and tribulations of a young boy (5-7years old) who is separated from his father after the plane they were traveling in crashes in a crocodile-infested river in the jungle somewhere in South America, I assume. Unfortunately, many of the surviving passengers were eaten by the crocodiles when they exited the wreckage. However, the boy's father was able to use a casket on board the ill-fated flight as a canoe to save his son from being eaten by the crocodiles before they were separated. 
The movie centers mainly around the boy and the challenges he faces in his effort to survive and reunite with his father--from almost being eaten by a python, being captured by a savage tribe, to being worshiped by another tribe as a god. And just when you think he's done for something happens or someone comes along who saves him only to have him on his own yet again. Whenever he got in a scrape or got scared he'd always call out for his father, screaming "Daddy! Daddy! Daddy!" The movie ends with him about to be offered as a sacrifice by another tribe. However, as he was calling out for his father yet again, his father heard his cries and was able to rescue him.

Terror in the Jungle:
Synopsis:

Little boy Henry Clayton Jr. survives a plane crash in the untamed Amazon jungle. However, he's discovered by a tribe of vicious savages who plan on sacrificing him. Meanwhile, Henry's father ventures into the jungle to find the missing lad before it's too late. 


Yes, I strongly agree with TurboPT, I just searched it up and sure enough, the description matches the plot of the movie. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063680/
